# method resolution with base types

Tags: c#, inheritance, method-resolution-order

My situation is this:

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        AnotherMethod();
    }
    public override void AnotherMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod()
    { }
    public virtual void AnotherMethod()
    { }
}
```

So which method is called when I call `InheritedClassInstance.SomeMethod`?  Does it call `InheritedClassInstance.AnotherMethod`, or the BaseClass's `AnotherMethod`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calls `InheritedClassInstance.AnotherMethod()`

If you wanted it to call the base class `AnotherMethod()` you would write `base.AnotherMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

It will call the derived method on the inherited class unless you explicitly call the base method (`base.AnotherMethod()`)