# module class's resolvemethod messes up on overridden methods

Tags: c#, module, resolve

I have a derived class with a method that overrides the base class's method, [(like this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667232/method-resolution-with-base-types)  but `module.ResolveMethod(token, typeArguments, methodArguments)` gives me a MethodBase with a declaringType of the base type, not the derived type like it should be.

Is this a bug in `module.ResolveMethod`?

The code is fairly complex to post, but I am using [Jb Evain's MethodBaseRocks](https://gist.github.com/104001/924302e1e226dfa3f5b5fd5678a3ac7d65c42a13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are using reflection/IL inspection. This is *static* code analysis. You are not doing anything on a specific runtime instance of a type.

Polymorphism is 'evaluated' at runtime: the runtime decides (based on the actual type of the object) which version of the virtual method to call (base or derived).

Your code seems to look a method up on a specific type, which will by definition return the method from that type, because you are inspecting the metadata as it is (the base declares the base method, the derived declares the derived method, nothing fancy; it's just the facts).

I think (IIRC) Mono.Cecil (from JbEvain) exposes an Overloads collection on the MethodDefinition. I suppose you may have to call MethodReference.Resolve() in order to get the MethodDefinition.

---

*more background if desired*:

There is no safe reflection way to invoke a virtual method according to runtime rules that apply when doing a `callvirt` in CIL. I.e. even if you do:

```
class BaseClass
{ public virtual void SomeMethod() {} }

class Derived :BaseClass {}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Action<Derived>> expr = (instance) => instance.SomeMethod();
        var method = (expr.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
        Console.WriteLine(method.DeclaringType);
    }
}
```

it will print `NamespaceName.BaseClass` because it is the class that declares the virtual.